# "Dereferencing Pointer to Incomplete Type" in provided code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stack

I am trying to write a program using code given to me by the author of my textbook, but I am getting "Dereferencing Pointer to Incomplete Type" errors in every method when trying to compile a program that uses the file. Below is the code. Does anyone know how I can fix this author's code to get it to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "StackADT.h"
#define STACK_SIZE 100

struct stackType {
    int contents[STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
};

static void terminate(const char *message) {
    printf("%s\n", message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Stack create(void) {
    Stack s = malloc(sizeof(struct stackType));

    if (s == NULL) {
        terminate("Error: Stack could not be created");
    }

    s->top = 0;
    return s;
}

void destroy(Stack s) {
    free(s);
}

void makeEmpty(Stack s) {
    s->top = 0;
}

bool isEmpty(Stack s) {
    return s->top == 0;
}

bool isFull(Stack s) {
    return s->top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(Stack s, Item i) {
    if (isFull(s)) {
        terminate("Error: Stack is full");
    }

    s->contents[s->top++] = i;
}

int pop(Stack s) {
    if (isEmpty(s)) {
        terminate("Error: Stack is empty");
    }

    return s->contents[--s->top];
}
```

Error:

```
StackADT.c: In function 'create':
StackADT.c:29: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c: In function 'makeEmpty':
StackADT.c:38: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c: In function 'isEmpty':
StackADT.c:42: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c: In function 'isFull':
StackADT.c:46: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c: In function 'push':
StackADT.c:54: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c:54: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c: In function 'pop':
StackADT.c:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackADT.c:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Comment: Can you give us the actual errors that are being produced?

Comment: We know what `stackType` is, but what is `Stack`? In the code, you treat `Stack` as if it was a `stackType`. In that case, why did you call the struct `stackType`, but in the rest of the code you refer to it as `Stack`?

Comment: I have appended the actual error to the main post. As for stackType vs. Stack, I have no idea, since I did not write this code. The author of the text wrote it, and I am simply trying to implement it.

Comment: What is provided on "StackADT.h"? Is there any '#typedef StackType *Stack' ? You have included this file while compiling, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try squeezing in `typedef struct stackType *Stack;` before the first function definition and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: What error do you get now?  The typedef should have resolved any issue with the structure not being defined.

Comment: Edit: I retyped it, and presumably I must've made a mistake, since it works now! Sorry for the confusion. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Cut'n'paste is your friend. :)

Comment: This is a completely bogus "solution". Since the compiler already recognizes `Stack` as a known typename that stands for some pointer type, `Stack` is already declared somewhere. (In `StackADT.h`?) Trying to redeclare it here will only sweep the problem under the carpet (if it will at all work).

Comment: Since the elements of whatever structure a `Stack` points to are the same as those in `struct stackType`, and since this a very simple program with a single struct definition, it seems a very safe bet that `Stack` was supposed to be synonymous with `struct stackType` all along. The OP's program does work.

Comment: @Ricky Stewart: This is not a program. This is just one translation unit in a program. I, for example, see no `main` function anywhere. By using this "band-aid" solution you only "fixed" this specific translation unit, while other translation units still see the original `Stack` definition.

Comment: @Ricky Stewart: I agree that `Stack` was probably supposed to stand for a pointer to this `struct stackType`. However, that means that either the original `Stack` declaration needs to be fixed, or this stack type name has to be fixed (I'd guess that it is a simple spelling problem, like `StackType` vs. `stackType`). Introducing a new typedef-declaration for `Stack` into this translation unit is a non-solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a previously declared pointer type `Stack` as a synonym for `struct stackType *`. In reality `Stack` has no relation to `struct stackType *`. Your `Stack` is declared as a synonym for `SomeOtherType *`, where `SomeOtherType` is some incomplete type.

Where is your `Stack` declaration? What does it say?